# How to resize and movable decals on 3d body with refrence to changes on 2d body?

Tags: threejs-editor, react-fiber

I'm working on a project and stucked on one part:

(React.js, Three.js)
Making decals movable and resizable with context of 2d changes side by side.
Anyhow I completed resizable part but changing position dynamically with reference to 2d body not working.

I also shared reference how actually it required:
T Shirt configurator - webGL / three.js
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=krIoFul_Sgs

If anyone had idea.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/36oXE.png)
I'm working on a project and stucked on one part:

(React.js, Three.js)
Making decals movable and resizable with context of 2d changes side by side.
Anyhow I completed resizable part but changing position dynamically with reference to 2d body not working.

I also shared reference how actually it required:
T Shirt configurator - webGL / three.js
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=krIoFul_Sgs

If anyone had idea.